# applying a map only to normal buffers

Tags: key-bindings

I have a binding that I use heavily and is very close to my heart. However, it tends to break (only a few) other functionality, primarily the command-line window.

The bind is normal mode :

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> Highlighting()
```

For completionism, here is Highlighting:

```
let g:highlighting = 1
function! Highlighting()
    let l:word = expand('let')
    if g:highlighting == 1 && @/ =~ '^\\<'.l:word.'\\>$'
        let g:highlighting = 0
        return ":silent nohlsearch\<CR>"
    endif
    let @/ = '\<'.l:word.'\>'
    " add to history -- can clutter, but def helps
    " NOTE! the item is added without /v so backspace first, then hunt
    call histadd('search', '\v<' . l:word . '>')
    let g:highlighting = 1
    " save this to file system (!) for fast workflow -- disabled now because its 
    " visually distracting and i need an async way to deal with this...
    " silent exe "!echo " . l:word . " > $HOME/.vim/.search"
    " redraw!
    if has('python')
        python << EOF
from os.path import expanduser
f = open(expanduser('~') + '/.vim/.search', 'w')
# print f
w = vim.eval("l:word")
f.write(w)
f.close()
EOF
    endif
    return ":silent set hlsearch\<CR>"
endfunction
```

OK, so, again, this is very useful and I use it *heavily*, so I cannot rebind it, but it actually prevents the command-line window from functioning because it means I can't actually run the command my cursor is on...

How can I mitigate this while still retaining the ease of use in normal mode in a regular buffer? For 5 years I've had this and avoided using the command-line window and now I am hoping to keep this functional and start being able to use the command-line window somehow.

Comment: I do not recommend mapping `<cr>`. You might check the buftype option.

Comment: @Mass I tried it and it does not work. Although I can tell that with `echo &buftype` it says `nofile` in the commandline window and provides no value when in a regular buffer.

Comment: @StevenLu sorry, try `nnoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> len(&buftype) ? '<cr>' : Highlighting()`

Comment: @Mass This ended up working! `nnoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> &buftype == "" ? Highlighting() : "<cr>"`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I might agree, because i am modifying behavior a lot here, but enter is actually the second largest non modifier button on the keyboard and there is a lot of ingrained muscle memory that I want to leverage. Since spacebar and enter are the two most readily mashed keys, I believe that it only makes sense to make their function deserving of their prominence: My spacebar scrolls down half a page, and my OP describes what I have my enter key do (`*` but smarter)